# Infinispan performance

Tags: performance, infinispan

Infinispan version 6.0.2.Final

I am looking into an issue where Infinispan put operations are occasionally taking longer than a second.

Cluster has 4 nodes and we are using replication mode. We have 2 application on each of the 4 nodes that uses embedded Infinispan.

The overall performance is perfectly ok as the average for all Infinispan operations is around 2-3 ms. Below is one example:

2015-10-15 16:29:02,048 DEBUG  InfinispanCacheListener        [Req-23] Infinispan cache: @CacheEntryCreated,  cacheName=duplicate, key=key;1810328342;356091;-828608960-0

2015-10-15 16:29:02,048 DEBUG  InfinispanCacheListener        [Req-23] Infinispan cache: @CacheEntryModified,  cacheName=duplicate, key=key;1810328342;356091;-828608960-0

2015-10-15 16:29:03,606 DEBUG  InfinispanCacheListener        [Req-23] Infinispan cache: @CacheEntryModified,  cacheName=duplicate, key=key;1810328342;356091;-828608960-0

2015-10-15 16:29:03,606 DEBUG  InfinispanCacheListener        [Req-23] Infinispan cache: @CacheEntryCreated,  cacheName=duplicate, key=key;1810328342;356091;-828608960-0

My understanding is that the first 2 events are before the operation is completed and the last 2 are after the entry is updated. We also have timer logic around the operation that confirms the delay.

In between, I can see Infinispan operations completing very quickly, example below.

2015-10-15 16:29:02,051 DEBUG  InfinispanCacheListener        [remote-thread-425] Infinispan cache: @CacheEntryCreated,  cacheName=answer, key=key;1810328342;356085;-828608958-0

2015-10-15 16:29:02,051 DEBUG  InfinispanCacheListener        [remote-thread-425] Infinispan cache: @CacheEntryModified,  cacheName=answer, key=key;1810328342;356085;-828608958-0

2015-10-15 16:29:02,051 DEBUG  InfinispanCacheListener        [remote-thread-425] Infinispan cache: @CacheEntryModified,  cacheName=answer, key=key;1810328342;356085;-828608958-0

2015-10-15 16:29:02,051 DEBUG  InfinispanCacheListener        [remote-thread-425] Infinispan cache: @CacheEntryCreated,  cacheName=answer, key=key;1810328342;356085;-828608958-0

1. I would like to know how to go about finding what is causing these spikes. Are there any usual suspects?
2. Why in the first example the event is reported by application thread and in the second example reported by remote-thread? I have seen sometimes it is reported by OOB threads. Both the events are locally generated.

Thanks
Rakesh

Answer (score 2):

I assume these are clustered listeners, right? If the local node is the primary owner of the key, it can fire the local listeners directly from the application thread that's issuing the operation. If the primary owner is a remote node, it has to send a message to the original node and this gets processed in the remote thread pool. When the thread pool is depleted, OOB thread needs to invoke that as the remote thread pool uses the caller runs policy. So that's why you see different threads invoking the listener.

Regarding the spikes: that's really hard to tell, you have to get trace logs and dig. Possible causes are message lost on network/dropped due to overloaded receiver, garbage collection, even stalls when logging to disk.

Comment: No these are not clustered listeners. Isn't support for clustered listener introduced in 7.0?